# Does Spring Data force dependency on SLF4j?

Tags: spring, logging, dependencies, spring-data

The Spring docs explicitly mention that spring only depends on on commons-logging.
However, if i add a dependency to Spring Data MongoDb, gradle adds a dependency on slf4j.

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.5.1.RELEASE       
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)           
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)          
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1                                   
\--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.1
```

Does this mean I am forced to use SLF4j if i use spring data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we have a compile time dependency on the Slf4j API as it's the de-facto standard logging API for Java and the one causing the least hassle of all the options available: JUL - I better don't leave a word on this one (see [this one](http://lightbody.net/blog/wp-content/plugins/really-static/static2/p=377/index.html) if you still need to be convinced), Commons Logging - runtime provider detection has [proven a PITA](http://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html).

We additionally require jcl-over-slf4j to provide a Commons Logging implementation to satisfy the Commons Logging dependency of the core Spring framework, a dependency it has to maintain for legacy reasons but would have [not been introduced in the first place](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) if Slf4j had been available back in the days.

So, yes. We're setting incentives to do the "right thing" (tm), read: "the way the Java community has agreed on at large". If you really want to stick to Commons Logging, simply add the slf4j-jcl bridge and you're set. If you want to remove the jcl-over-slf4j bridge, simply exclude the dependency.

Comment: the issue is not with slf4j per se, its with the fact that the documentation doesnt match the reality. The documentation says spring uses commons-logging and need to be updated if that is not the case.

Comment: YOu didn't mention that in the question :). Care to share a link to the places you found the misleading information so that I can fix it?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging

Comment: This is the reference documentation for Spring Framework, not Spring Data…

Comment: yes, but spring data documentation doesnt say it changes the logging frameowrks. a newcomer to spring like myself will assume the spring framework documentation holds true for spring data too, especially considering that most spring projects will indeed use spring data

Comment: Well, I am not sure what we can do here. You're also not assuming we'r e inheriting logging setup from dependent libraies like Hibernate of MongoDB, do you?

Comment: either way, the spring data documentation should document which logging framework is being used by it (which it currently does not)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable SLF4J logging in Spring Data by adding to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        <!-- Exclude slf4j logging in favor of log4j -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is only a Logging Facade that in spring case will delegate in commons logging, using the jcl-over-slf4j dependency.

If you want your app to use commons-logging you can simply exclude slf4j dependencies.